# Open new tab after Safari App Extension is enabled

Tags: safari, safari-extension, apple-developer

I'm looking for a way to watch state of extension and open a new tab automatically, once it is enabled.

Previously I was relying on a `SFSafariExtensionManager.getStateOfSafariExtension, but it has to be called manually from UI, so that don't really work fork me.

Also I'm not sure which app should be responsible for opening a new tab (Container app of `NSApplicationMain` or Extension handler `SFSafariExtensionHandler`)